# Merge 3 dataframes where 2 dataframes have unique ids but 3rd has a combination of unique ids of the other 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am looking for the best way to merge following 3 input dataframes:
df1

```
    proj_id doc_id
0   11  21
1   12  22
2   13  23
3   14  24
4   15  25
5   15  26
6   16  26
```

df2 (proj_id is unique id)

```
    proj_id info1   info2
0   11  1   a
1   12  2   b
2   13  3   c
3   14  4   d
4   15  5   e
5   16  6   f
6   17  7   g
```

df3 (doc_id is unique id)

```
    doc_id  doc_info1   doc_info2
0   21  uu  33
1   22  uv  32
2   23  uw  34
3   24  ux  35
4   25  uz  36
5   26  ua  37
6   27  ub  38
```

So the output should have information on proj_id and doc_ids from df2 and df3 into df1 as shown below.
output_df:

```
    proj_id doc_id  info1   info2   doc_info1   doc_info2
0   11  21  1   a   uu  33
1   12  22  2   b   uv  32
2   13  23  3   c   uw  34
3   14  24  4   d   ux  35
4   15  25  5   e   uz  36
5   15  26  5   e   ua  37
6   16  26  6   f   ua  37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)  with left join:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='proj_id', how='left').merge(df3, on='doc_id', how='left')
```